# Condition before inserting an item and show message in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, api

I'm developing an application in React.JS

I need to put a condition before inserting.

The code:

```
const App = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState([])
    const [category, setCategory] = useState([])

    const categories = category.map(elem => ({
        value: elem.id,
        label: elem.cat,
    }));

    const [category_select, setCategorySelect] = React.useState(null);

    function handleChangeCategory(value) {
        setCategorySelect(value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories()
    }, [])

    const getItems = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(REQUEST_1)
        setItem(response.data)
    }

    const getCategories = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(REQUEST_2)
        setCategory(response.data)
    }

    const addItems = () => {
        axios.post(`${REQUEST_1}`, {cat: category_select.value});
    };

    const body = () => {
        return item && item.map((elem,j) => {
            return (
                <tr key={elem.id}>
                    <td><span>{elem.cat}</span></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <NoSsr>
                                <Select
                                    classes={classes}
                                    styles={selectStyles}
                                    inputId="category"
                                    TextFieldProps={{
                                        label: 'Category',
                                        InputLabelProps: {
                                        htmlFor: 'category',
                                        shrink: true,
                                        },
                                        placeholder: 'Category...',
                                    }}
                                    options={categories}
                                    components={components}
                                    value={category}
                                    onChange={handleChangeCategory}
                                />
                            </NoSsr>
                            <span>Select</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <span onClick={addItems}></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <span>Category</span>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {body()}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

The idea is to check if the item to be inserted already exists, and if it is already inserted, show a message through a popup.

How do I add this condition in the `const addItems = () => {...}` and the popup? Do I have to put that condition here?

How can I do it, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the selected category already exists in `addItems` method.

You can use React packages like `reactjs-popup` to display a popup.

```js
const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false)

const addItems = () => {
    // check if selected category already exists
    if (!category.some(elem => elem.cat === category_select.value)) { 
        axios.post(`${REQUEST_1}`, {cat: category_select.value});
    }
    else {
        // update popup modal open state and display popup
        setIsShow(true);
    }
};

...
return (
...
{ isShow && <h1>Error</h1> }
...)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help! How to return the popup? I tried for example with this `else {return (<h1>hello</h1>);}`, but it does not show anything

Comment: Hey @bonnegnu, it's not a render function. Just handle add item logic. If you want to render something, you should update the display state of the element you want to show.
Then display the element in the return function according to its state.